# Find $x$ such that $(ax)^{bx}>c$, where $a,b,c,x>0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function, supremum-and-infimum

Let $a>0$, $b>0$, and $c>0$. Let  $$x_0\triangleq \inf\{x>0:{\rm for~all~} \bar x>x, (a\bar x)^{b\bar x}>c\}.$$
What is a good estimate (least-conservative estimate) for $x_0?$

Comment: Is $x$ a positive real number?

Comment: Yes, $x$ is a positive real number.

Comment: Not really an answer, but note that by substituting $y=ax$ it's enough to find $y_0 := \inf\{y > 0 : y^{dy} > c\}$ for $d=\frac{b}{a}$ (if you find good estimate for $y_0$ then $x_0 = \frac{y_0}{a}$ will do in your case. Moreover, looking at $y_0$, we have $(y^y)^{d} > c$ under supremum, so again, it boils down to good estimate for $\inf\{ y>0 : y^y > z \}$ for some constant $z=\ln_d(c)$ (if $d=1$ we need to put $z=c$). Maybe it can help a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can begin by simplifying the inequality like this:
$$(a x)^{b x}>c$$
set $a x=y$ so $x = y/a$
$$y^{by/a}>c$$
now raise to the power $a/b$ to get
$$y^y>c^{a/b}$$
Calling $d = c^{a/b}$
your inequality simplifies to $$y^y>d$$

As already was observed, this leads to solve the equation $y^y=d$, whose solution is given by $y = \frac{\log(d)}{W(\log(d))}$ where $W$ is the [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Can you take it from here?